# How do I get my proc univariate output to not show in scientific notation?

Tags: sas, format

Example of when it is showing scientific notation when unwanted:

Quantiles (Definition 5)
Level   Quantile

100% Max    3.2E+01

50% Median  5.4E+00

0% Min      2.1E-01

```
proc univariate data=lib.data plots;
var cr  gl in fe;
histogram cr gl in fe/normal;
run;
```

Comment: Are you talking about the report that PROC UNIVARIATE prints?  Or the dataset that it can produce?  Please show the code you used.

Comment: @Tom the report it prints I think. Maybe both. I've added code to the question.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your exact issue even if I force the format to `e.`